# I need to send multiple clients a python file and have them all execute it, then download the result

Tags: python

So here's the deal. I have a server that has a ton of clients. I need a way to send them all a python script, and once they receive it they must immediately execute the script. 
Said script will create a file which I then need to download back to the server.
The only thing I have to start with is a file with a list of client IP addresses (though with not too much effort I can change that to be client "names" if that would make the code easier).

As of right now it does not matter whether this is accomplished through POST or FTP or any other file transfer service you can think of, the only goal is that it is fast.
The script that is being executed on all the clients is a simple key generator, which I can provide if need be.

As said before the main goal of this needs to be speed, any help that can be provided would be appreciated.

Im part of a project trying to "map" the internet. I was picked, not because of any sort of networking skills (of which i have none) but because i was the only candidate that knew any python. Right now im just trying to establish a connection with all the (1000+) clients we are using and get the ssh (rsa) keys from them. Later i will be telling the clients to send traceroutes.

**EDIT** ---- provided additional information to make the question clearer

Comment: What kind of access do you have to the compute nodes that would allow you to execute code?  SSH?  Some kind of batch system?

Comment: The implications of forcing a client to execute a script as soon as it receives it from the server are staggering.  HTTP isn't designed for this, and neither is FTP.  Not to mention, what are you going to do if the clients don't have Python installed?  They can't execute the script without it.  If you've compiled the script in some way they'll have to have a runtime environment for Python installed.  Too many variables here, and it's dangerous besides.

Comment: Are the compute nodes on a local network?  What kind of SSH authentication are you using? What platform? Do the compute nodes have a homogeneous environment you can rely on?

Comment: @g.d.d.c your right, immediately was probably the wrong word... how about as soon as possible? This is a time sensitive environment and quick response time is critical. As for the clients not having python installed, I can convert the script to an executable if you feel that would be safer. Unless you have a better idea?

Comment: @SvenMarnach no the nodes are not on a local network, they are all around the globe. rsa, but I havent been able to test it yet so the remote access may be a problem

Comment: The problem is not "immediacy" but "automaticness". Say one of the client computers is mine. Why should I allow my computer to receive a Python script from the server without asking for it, and then to run it and trust that it won't harm my computer? What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Im part of a project trying to "map" the internet. I was picked, not because of any sort of networking skills (of which i have none) but because i was the only candidate that knew any python. Right now im just trying to establish a connection with all the (1000+) clients we are using and get the ssh keys from them. Later i will be telling the clients to send traceroutes.

Comment: @AdamP:  OK, now we start getting the picture.  Consider to update your original question with the addtional information.  So what are the platforms of the clients?  Do they have any tools you can rely on?

Comment: @SvenMarnach so the only things I know about the clients are their geographical location (in longitude and latitude) their IP and/or "name" and whether they are currently on or off. There are a few other bits of information we store on clients most of which i cannot access, and all of which i cannot give out. In specific response to your question, they do not have any sort of uniform platform but it can be assumed that they will have the ability to accept Unix commands.

Comment: @AdamP: "Unix commands" is a bit vague and could mean anything or nothing, but I'll try an answer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach sorry, i wasnt trying to be vague. I mean you can run unix shell (or terminal sorry my terminology isnt great) commands. As in something along the lines of subprocess.Popen("man man") should work. (assuming i got the syntax correct)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.2/index.html).  It is a tool that exactly fits what you need, though I don't know how fast it is.

Comment: Thank you, this does appear to have the everything I need. Ill request an installation on the server and see if i cant get some small scale test set up by thursday or at least next tuesday. Ill let you know how it works. Thank you for all your time and help.